# Move a view up so textfield does not disappear behind keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, keyboard-events

I have a view like you can see over here.
[image]

You can see that I have an header image with below a lot of textfields. Only the UITextfields Adres - Postcode - Gemeente - Tel.nr - Email  - BTWnr. are disappearing behind the keyboard. 
I have some code, that is working for the UITextfield of Adres. But when I want to implement more it always takes the animation for the UITextfield of Adres.

Here is what I have in code

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 80.0
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD2 120.0
-(void)keyboardWillShow {

    NSLog(@"Keyboard frame now is %f",self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y);
    // Animate the current view out of the way
    if (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y >= 198)
    {
        NSLog(@"keyboardWillShow 1");
        [self setViewMovedUp2:NO];
    }
    else if (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y < 198)
    {
         NSLog(@"keyboardWillShow 2");
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {

    NSLog(@"Keyboard frame  ATM %f",self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y);
    if (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y >= 198)
    {
        NSLog(@"keyboardWillHide 1");
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y < 198)
    {
        NSLog(@"keyboardWillHide 2");
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{

    if ([sender isEqual:txtAdres])
    {
        NSLog(@"sender is adres");
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y >= 198)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
    if ([sender isEqual:txtPostcode])
    {
        NSLog(@"sender is postcode");
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.keyboardView.frame.origin.y >= 198)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp2:YES];
        }
    }
}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.keyboardView.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.keyboardView.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)setViewMovedUp2:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    NSLog(@"setViewMovedUp2 called");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.keyboardView.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD2;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD2;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD2;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD2;
    }
    self.keyboardView.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And in my ViewWillAppear I do this

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one ...I hope it may help you. And you can put your value on 200 in this line where you wanna your textfield.

```
 CGFloat avaliableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200;


- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView
{
    CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGFloat avaliableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200;

    CGFloat y = viewCenterY - avaliableHeight / 2.0f;

    if (y < 0)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest , use a dropin replacement library [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) which handles all the work for moving the views, when  Keyboard is shown, Its a Very easy way of achieving that

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across this problem yesterday. Here's my code:

```
#define kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD 80.0
//This decides how many pixels to move the view

 -(void)keyboardWillShow
{
    // Animate the current view out of the way
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide
{
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:doNotCover])
    {
        //move the main view, so that the keyboard does not hide it.
        if  (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
        {
            [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
        }
    }
}

//method to move the view up/down whenever the keyboard is shown/dismissed
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

    if (movedUp)
    {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```